# Rank of a random variable that follows a Uniform Distribution (0,1)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Well the question is a little easier .. Let X be a random variable that follows a Uniform distribution (0,1)(Uniform Standard). What is rank of the variable? (Values ​​can take). I have a confusion between whether the variable can take real values ​​between the interval (0,1) or can only take the values ​​0 or 1

Comment: Can you write the density function for $X$ uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$? Those points with non-zero probability belong to the rank of $X$!

Comment: @Kanna: Be careful that here, **every** point has zero probability... I see what you mean to ask by your second question but it needs to be slightly reformulated.

Comment: @DidierPiau Thank You very much! Sure, I meant "non-zero density"!

Comment: @Kan: Yes. With the further caveat that the density function is only defined almost surely... Hence for every point there exists a density function which is zero at this point... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let X be a random variable that follows a
>   Uniform distribution (0,1)(Uniform Standard).

Do you mean a discrete or a continuous distribution?  Do you mean [0,1] or (0,1)?  Or are these your questions?

Comment: Sorry is a continuos distribution. that is X ~ Uniform (0,1). I thought that the random variable that follows a standard uniform distribution is understood to be a continuous distribution (by [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)))

Comment: Melkhiah: If the definition is well known to you, why do you ask this question?